# running npm install @nuxtjs/sentry doesn't work with node version v16.15.0

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I recently switched my laptop and cloned my project which was already working fine on the other laptop, when I installed node js in new laptop with version v16.15.0 and tried running "npm install" in my nuxt project as you can see in screen shot below. and gives error while installing @nuxtjs/sentry
[image: ERROR IMAGE]

also removing sentry package from package.json and nuxt.config.js and then running npm install to have all other dependencies works just fine.

And running "npm install @nuxtjs/sentry" gives the same error too.

Comment: NPM is really bad at hinting about errors IMO. Could you try to install the dependencies with `yarn` please?

Comment: Also, could you try with node 14? And also share your `package.json` +`nuxt.config.js` files please?

Comment: i looked and its having issues downloading and installing sentry CLI with @nuxtjs/sentry;

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact error?

Comment: Thats the exact error I am getting which is shown in screen shot.

Comment: The other machine is a Windows too?

Comment: Yes, both are windows.

Comment: A [repro] or a Github repo is highly recommended here I guess.

Comment: @kissu I need help with the problem. Facing the same.

Comment: @nik feel free to post a new question and provide as much feedback as you can to let us see how this can be replicated.

Comment: @kissu Can you check my profile? I just did.